# When I reset my iPhone, will it deactive my service with my carrier?

Tags: iphone

I have the iPhone 5s that is 16 GB. I deleted many apps and photos, but I still have no storage and memory. My only option is to restart my iPhone completely, meaning to erase all my data and media on it. I'm
wondering if this was disconnect the service with my Verizon carrier...

Answer (score 5):

The phone is connected to Verizon via the SIM card, not the phone itself. So, no, reseting your phone will not deactivate your service.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. Your iPhone will activate itself automatically upon startup.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who reads this and has a problem where their phone does deactivate the carrier you can still have it reactivated and keep the same number.  they cannot give your number to anyone else for 60 days after deactivation of service.

Answer (score -1):

The other two answers are false when restoring my old iPhone once it did deactivate it. My carrier advised I had to call to reactivate it. Take it to the Apple Store if you really need it restored it sounds like the part that reads the memory storage has gone wonky. It only won't if you restore from a back up its advised to use an iCloud back up rather then iTunes 
Note:I just restored it as new and I did deactivate it my phone number was gone so please spell me you didn't listen to them

Comment: There is a small possibility that your carrier would require contact to reactivate a device which has been wiped and set up as new, but for the _vast_ majority of carriers, the only thing that matters is the SIM card, and that is not affected by wiping the device.